# running a tkinter multiple Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making my first tkinter program and when I run the code bellow I get a an error:

> frame = F(window,self )
> TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given"

and I cant find out why.

Code:

```
class welcome_screen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        
        lable = tk.Label(self,text="Step Cyber",bg = "gold", width = "500",height = "1", font=("Calibri",45)).pack()
        label.pack()
        lable = tk.Label(self,text="Welcome to The Step Cyber. Access computer as Client or Admin", font=("Calibri")).pack()
        label.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self,text="Client",width = "30",height = "2",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(client_sceen) ).pack()
        button.pack()
        tk.Label(self,text="").pack()
        button = tk.Button(self,text="Administrator",width = "30",height = "2", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(admin_login)).pack() 
        button.pack()
```

This is the class I use to create the window and change frames, the one above is one of other multiple classes frames. What might be the problem. Thank you in advance

```
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        #creating a window
        window = tk.Frame(self)
        window.pack()

        window.grid_rowconfigure(0,minsize = 800)
        window.grid_columnconfigure(0,minsize= 800)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (welcome_screen,client_sceen,timer_screen,admin_login,admin_screen,Regester_Admin_screen):
            frame = F(window,self )
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew" )

        self.show_frame(welcome_screen)

    def show_frame(self,page):
        frame = self.frames[page]
        frame.tkraise()

app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you passing in `self` as an argument ~ `F(window,self )`. Which raises the question, `tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)` why are there two parent windows for the frame?

Comment: The exception may not related to `welcome_screen`, but other classes, like `client_screen`, `timer_screen`, etc.